# Receiving the following error with my query when calculating distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm receiving the following error "An invalid floating point operation occurred." when I run this query:

```
SELECT PolID, LocID, Address, City, StateCode, OrigGeoLat, OrigGeoLong, NewGeoLat, NewGeoLong, 
acos(sin(radians(OrigGeoLat)) * sin(radians(NewGeoLat)) +
        cos(radians(OrigGeoLat)) * cos(radians(NewGeoLat)) *
        cos(radians(OrigGeoLong - NewGeoLong))) * 6372.8  as Distance
FROM zzGeoDataTMP
```

All of the *geoLat and *geoLong data is defined as numeric(18,10).  When I run the query I start getting data back and then I get errors on specific rows of data.  For example the following row throws the above mentioned exception only once the ACOS function is called:

```
OrigGeoLat|OrigGeoLong|NewGeoLat|NewGeoLong
---------------------------------------------
32.9364620|-80.0411000|32.9364620|-80.0411000
```

Thanks so much in advance for any insight you may be able to help with!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the `geography` type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calculation is accumulating some small errors, which mean that the calculated value (passed to `ACOS`) is *slightly* higher than 1. Try wrapping it with a [`ROUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) call:

```
acos(ROUND(sin(radians(OrigGeoLat)) * sin(radians(NewGeoLat)) +
    cos(radians(OrigGeoLat)) * cos(radians(NewGeoLat)) *
    cos(radians(OrigGeoLong - NewGeoLong)),15)
    )
```

Where we're *only* keeping 15 decimal places of accuracy.

Comment: If that doesn't catch all the errors, this could be safer: CASE WHEN [trig_expression] > 1 THEN 1 WHEN [trig_expression] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [trig_expression] END. If you don't like the triplicating the expression, you might try wrapping [trig_expression] in a cte or derived table or even writing a function.